# How to make my adjust monitor brightness by a simple soft

Tags: display, multiple-monitors, brightness

I have two monitor,  one is benq BL2410PT , another is ausu vx279.

I have tried below two soft:

http://noeld.com/programs.asp#Display  ([How do I set up a hotkey or shortcut to rotate my screen in Windows?](https://superuser.com/questions/447155/how-do-i-set-up-a-hotkey-or-shortcut-to-rotate-my-screen-in-windows)   it support brightness too)

http://freemonitormanager.com/index.html

They all can adjust ausu's brightness, but can't change benq. Why ??  less some setting ? I really don't know much about monitor.

How can I make benq be adjusted by Display.exe or freemonitormanager ?

PS: My video card is amd 6850(old card, old ccc doesn't support shortcut), I know ccc can adjust both monitor's brightness . But what I most concern is shortcut , freemonitormanager has shortcut build-in, and Display.exe(command-line tool) can use with AutoHotKey .

Comment: related: https://superuser.com/questions/308415/how-can-i-dim-my-computer-screen-beyond-the-minimum

Comment: Thanks for the reference to FreeMonitorManager!  It's working for my BenQ!!  I tried other apps, and none other worked - Monitorian (worked for a month then stopped recognizing external BenQ); ClickMonitorDDC (brightness sliders for both monitors were adjusting the internal monitor, not external).

Answer (score 0):

Some monitor do not have internal brightness control, maybe your Ausu monitor don't have internal brightness control.

Using a external brightness control software like
[Dimmer](http://www.nelsonpires.com/software/dimmer/) might helps you, but it is for windows only.

Comment: It is benq can't adjust brightness .  Dimmer looks like use a grey overlayer ?  Unfortunately, it only can change the main monitor's brightness, and don't support shortcut ...